Use of "would" rather than "is"
In this dialogue, Speaker B uses "would" when answering A's question. Can you explain why use "would" rather than "is?"

A: Ronaldo wore this?
Is my question idiomatic?
B: If you say it like that, it sounds as though you’ve been told he did
wear it but you don’t believe it.
The normal question format would be “Did Ronaldo wear this?”


We can use 'would' about hypothetical or unreal situations or things, such as a question which has not been asked.

would be is more "indirect" than is, so it may simply reflect the fact that the speaker / writer isn't 100% certain of what he's asserting. Or that he doesn't like to present things too forcefully if he thinks his audience might disagree. Or that he thinks it sounds a bit more "polite" and/or "sophisticated" to say "I think that would be true" rather than "I know that is true".

@FumbleFingers Can you explain what's meant by "indirect" would?

The possible meanings are explained in the rest of the comment!

If you wanted to pose the question, the form the question normally takes would be  "Did  ______?".     It is a conditional with an implicit  protasis, provided by context, there the context being a discussion of the proper way to ask the question.

Compare “would be” vs. “is”, would it be vs is it, to be or would be

@FumbleFingers The OP has opened a dup and your comment here seems like the best input they've gotten so far. May I suggest you turn it into an answer?

Using "would be"

The normal question format would be “Did Ronaldo wear this?”

We use "would" in the result clause of the Second Conditional. (imaginary situation or hypothetical if condition)
Implied conditional.
The second conditional can be written without the if condition
For example:
1."I wouldn't do that!" (If I were you).
2."What would you do in this situation?"  (If you were in my place).
For more examples, do a search for "would" + verb on
https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/.
Similarly OP's sentence can be considered a "second conditional sentence".
The structure is usually:
if + past simple >> + would + infinitive.
If you got a chance to ask, the normal question format would be “Did Ronaldo wear this?”

would be is more "indirect" than is, so it may simply reflect the fact that the speaker / writer isn't 100% certain of what he's asserting.
Or that he doesn't like to present things too forcefully (especially if he thinks his audience might disagree). Or that he thinks it sounds a bit more "polite" and/or "sophisticated" to say "I think that would be true" rather than "I know that is true".
